# 不味い versus 嫌い with food

Tags: word-choice, food

I posted a sentence to be corrected which was:

> 私は辛い野菜が不味い。

and they told me to use 「嫌い」 instead of 「不味い」.

What is the difference between the two when it comes to food?

Comment: Use of kanji for まずい is not very common. Suggest sticking with the standard hiragana for most applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私は辛い野菜が嫌い makes sense because this is the grammar pattern used to talk about things you like or do not like.

- 私は...が嫌い
- 私は...が好き

I think it's important to note that both 嫌い and 好き are nouns.

Really, they are nominalized verbs,

- 嫌う(to dislike) → 嫌い(something disliked)
- 好く(to like) → 好き(something liked)

You might think of the Japanese grammar as saying something like,

- "***I have*** a dislike for spicy vegetables."

私は辛い野菜が不味い is incorrect because this is not the grammar pattern used to talk about whether you think something is tasty or not. 不味い is an i-adjective, meaning "bad tasting".

The correct grammar pattern for telling someone what you think is tasty or not (assuming you want to use 私は) would be,

- 私は辛い野菜が不味い**と思う**.

If you don't say the と思う part, then it is similar to saying *"**I have** spicy vegetables taste bad"* in English.

There are two ways to fix this, either remove "I" and change the topic to "spicy vegetables" or add "think"...

- **辛い野菜は**不味い → "Spicy vegetables taste bad"
- 私は辛い野菜が不味い**と思う** → "I think spicy vegetables taste bad"

Comment: How about if you change 私は to 私には? Would the OP's sentence work then?

Comment: I feel like 私には辛い野菜が不味い is probably grammatically OK, but wouldn't be the most common way to say it.